# Is it possible to pass different arguments in the constructor during the execution of new?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

Let's say I have a class with its constructor:

```
Class MyClass {
  public:
     MyClass(int arg);
  private:
     int a;
};
```

and a global array:

```
int MyArray[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

I want to have a dynamic array of pointers to MyClass but each element of the array must call the constructor with different number. I was trying to do something like that but it did not work out

```
int main()
{
   int i=0;
   MyClass *MyDynArray = new MyClass[10]{MyArray[i++]};
}
```

Is it possible to do this in C++ without using vectors? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it the same way as you declared the array with the automatic or static storage duration.

```
MyClass *MyDynArray = new MyClass[10]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Looking to your answer created another question to me. What if the size of MyDynArray is a variable and we do not know exactly how many elements we will have in the array?

Comment: @DimK In this case you need to use a template.